# Equivalent of IServiceLocator for serialization

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, json.net, protobuf-net

The `IServiceLocator` interface from Microsoft's `CommonServiceLocator` library provides injection framework providers an interface to build on and library writers an interface to depend upon.

Is there some equivalent to this for serialization?

I'd like to allow the user of my library to choose between `Protobuf` and `Json.NET` and any other serialization framework easily. If I provide the abstraction as part of my library I feel compelled to write some basic implementations as well.

It's additional `Nuget` packages that would be better in a general-use scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up making my own:
https://github.com/BrannonKing/CommonSerializer

I needed a lot of control over the library for testing timings.

Also, I encountered this one along the way:
https://github.com/EsWork/Es.Serializer